# why I dont receive an error if show method does not exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
# routes.rb
resources :resource

# resources_controller.rb
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  # no methods here
end

# show.html.erb
# file exists
```

It renders show.html.erb, why I don't receive an error saying that `ResourcesController#show` does not exist?, on the log i see request handled by `ResourcesController#show` even when that method does not exists.

I found this danger.

Comment: if you find that danger, consider adding to your routes: `resources :something, only: [:index]` or whatever you want to route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the guides. In particular [Rendering by Default: Convention Over Configuration in Action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).

As the guide says:

> By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to valid routes.